# My dog licks up his own urine

Tags: dogs

My 18 year old Jack Russel will lap up his own urine when he urinates on the floor by accident. Why does he do this?

Comment: I just came across this site. Not a duplicate post. Just wondering if it's old age or if he is lacking in something.

Comment: I suspect that the linked post probably covers it, really. The reasons are going to be much the same.

Comment: @Shell We are not suggesting that you posted the question twice, we are saying the nearly identical question has already been asked.  We work a little different than other site you may have visited.

Comment: If your question gets closed as a duplicate it's not a criticism of you at all - sometimes you just don't know the right search words to look for before asking. But we aim to be a comprehensive timeless resource for all pets Q&A, not just a forum. That means that we tidy things up, like if the same question gets asked twice, so that it is easier for future viewers to find the answers to their questions and to stop the site from getting too cluttered. I hope the linked question solves your problem for you - and welcome to the site!

Comment: If the linked post does not provide the answers you're looking for, or if you feel your situation is different from what is presented in the linked post, please [edit your question](http://pets.stackexchange.com/posts/9253/edit) with the details and we'll reopen it.